# Type casting, a runtime alternative to Cast<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have an `IList<object>` where every single object is an instance of a type `T` (which I don't know at compile-time).

I need an `IList<T>` out of this. I can't use Cast since I don't know the type at compile time, and there isn't a Cast(Type) overload I could use.

This is what I currently have in place:

```
private object Map(IList<ApiCallContext> bulk)
{
    // god-awful way to build a IEnumerable<modelType> list out of Enumerable<object> where object is modelType.
    // quoting lead: "think whatever you do it will be ugly"
    Type modelType = model.Method.ModelType;

    if (bulk.Count > 0)
    {
        modelType = bulk.First().Parameters.GetType();
    }
    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(modelType);
    object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    foreach (object value in bulk.Select(r => r.Parameters))
    {
        ((IList)list).Add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

What I'm thinking about is maybe I could create a new `LooseList` class that implements `IList` and just works around the casting, seems better than what I currently have but it still sounds way too clunky.

Comment: May I ask what's the goal of this? If you cannot know T at compile time, you will not be able to use your IList<T> in a strongly-typed manner, right?

Comment: The point is I need to feed a library with this list, which uses generics to parse the list and write to a CSV file.

Comment: What does the method you need to feed look like? Does it take `List<T>` for any `T`, or is it fixed to some particular value?

Comment: `void WriteRecords<T>(IEnumerable<T> rows)`. That's beside the point. somewhere down the line they try to build an expression using `T` to get the properties in my type; and that blows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to do exactly as you've stated, I'd first separate this out into "context-specific code" and "reusable code". Effectively you want something like this:

```
public static IList ToStrongList(this IEnumerable source, Type targetType)
```

I would *implement* that by writin a strongly-typed method, and then calling it via reflection:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo ToStrongListMethod = typeof(...)
    .GetMethod("ToStrongListImpl", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

public static IList ToStrongList(this IEnumerable source, Type targetType)
{
    var method = ToStrongListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
    return (IList) method.Invoke(null, new object[] { source });
}

private static List<T> ToStrongListImpl<T>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    return source.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: You're still going to need reflection to call the `WriteRecords<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` method as well, since you can't call it directly without a statically-known type.

Comment: @Porges: Reflection or `dynamic`, which of course will use reflection behind the scenes, but is simpler from a coding point of view :)

Comment: But `targetType` is not known when you call `ToStrongList`, unless you do some inspection before doing the call, at that point why do not do that inside `ToStringList` itself?

Comment: @Wasp: The point is that you'd do the inspection within `Map`, in the way that it's already doing... and by calling the generic method with reflection, we only need to use reflection *once*, instead of once to call `Cast<T>` and once to call `ToList<T>`.

Comment: Ok, clear, I thought that `ToStrongList` was meant to replace `Map`, that's why I was highlighting that point and thinking that it would have to go into `ToStringList` :)

Comment: @Porges yeah; I was already doing that though, but the code to cast the list felt hideously wrong.