# I need a Linq IEnumerable<>.Cast(typeof(T))

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, ienumerable

I'm querying a data structure and the result type is `IEnumerable<IEntry>` (`IEntry` being a framework interface), each entry has a `Data` property (of type object) which is interseting for me.

My code looks like this:

```
var resultList = framework.QueryAllOfType(queryClause.Type)
                          .Select(e => e.Data)
                          .ToList();
deleagte.DynamicInvoke(new[]{resultList});
```

The method behind the delegate looks something like this:

```
void Foo (IEnumerable<SomeType> bar); // if queryClause.Type == typeof(SomeType)
void Foo (IEnumerable<OtherType> bar); // if queryClause.Type == typeof(OtherType)
```

I'm absolutely positive that `queryClause.Type` matches `SomeType`, of course however, the .NET framework is not ;-)

Unfortunately this means that the `resultList` is of type `IEnumerable<object>` although all the objects within are of the correct type, I'm not able to call the delegate (exception: `IEnumerable<object> cannot be converted into IEnumerable<SomeType>`).

I know why this is the case, but what's the solution? I would need something along the lines of:

`.Select(e => e.Data).Cast(queryClause.Type).ToList()` which should return an `IEnumerable<queryClause.Type>`. Is there such a thing already somewhere in the .NET framework? Is there a better solution?

**Important:** As two answers already misunderstood my intensions, I cannot use the type as a generic parameter as it is known at runtime only. Therefore all `Cast<...>()`, `Select(e =e as ...)`, etc. do not work.

Comment: I don't understand that: you have a delegate that does not accept an IEnumerable<object> but needs another type, yet you claim the type is not compile time? How did the delegate know?

Comment: There are of course more delegates - all having different parameter types (which is why I need DynamicInvoke to call them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke `Cast` using reflection:

```
var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(queryClause.Type);
IEnumerable<object> cSeq = (IEnumerable<object>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { resultList });

deleagte.DynamicInvoke(new[]{ cSeq });
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. In the meantime I've found that solution myself. Hoped that there is something already in the .NET framework.

Comment: This does not work, because after calling `Cast()` you need to call `ToList()` again in order to call the delegate, which once more returns an `IList<object>`.

Comment: You have to combine Cast/ToList into a single call, with the `MakeGenericMethod` keyword I've now found this answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12848842/1400869 which seems to be a working solution.

Comment: @D.R. - Your question says the delegate takes an `IEnumerable<T>` not a `List<T>` so this should work. If you need to pass a `List<T>` then you will have to invoke `ToList<T>` using reflection in the same way as `Cast<T>`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna accept your answer. Just left the link here because probably some other guy will stumble over it too.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your feedback and using the other answers I've created a `ToListOfType()` extension method that should do what you need.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    private static readonly Type _enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);

    public static IEnumerable CastAsType(this IEnumerable source, Type targetType)
    {
        var castMethod = _enumerableType.GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(targetType);

        return (IEnumerable)castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source });
    } 

    public static IList ToListOfType(this IEnumerable source, Type targetType)
    {
        var enumerable = CastAsType(source, targetType);

        var listMethod = _enumerableType.GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(targetType);

        return (IList)listMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { enumerable });
    } 
}
```

This should work with your delegate if you simply replace your `ToList()` call with `ToListOfType(queryClause.Type)`. I implemented both the `CastAsType` and `ToListOfType` methods so that you can leave the collection un-iterated if you so choose.  I'll note for future readers that these are only useful in a situation like yours where you're passing the result off to a delegate dynamically - the `Cast<T>` operation would be preferred in all other cases.

Comment: This does not have any effect on the behavior of ToList(). `e.Data` already is of type `queryClause.Type`, however, the compiler does not know, which is why `.ToList()` returns an `IList<object>`.

Comment: @D.R. - updated with extension methods that integrate the accepted answer without the additional per-class methods needed by the answer you referenced in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to finish with something like:

```
.ToList<IEntry>()
```

is like for example if you do something like:

int[] text = {01, 2, 3, 4, 5};

```
List<string> list = text.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: I've updated my question, this is no possible solution for me.

Comment: OK! so sorry then dude! ;)